# Increasing file upload limit in apache httpd file

Tags: apache

My cilent is using Apache server deployed on Linux OS. Application allows files upto 50MB but its throwing errors when uploaded more than 2MB. I searched online and found limit can be increased by below options:
`post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize`

But these two parameters are not found in `httpd` file. So could anyone here please help me which values i need to set to increase file upload limit?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything in your httpd file.

For increase files size you need to edit php.ini where you find this two optins :
 post_max_size & upload_max_filesize

For Windows, you can find the file in the C:\xampp\php\php.ini-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder).

Under Linux, most distributions put lampp under /opt/lampp, so the file can be found under /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini.

Find and set the following two values:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Save and close the file and restart Apache server.

Comment: Hi, My Client didnt install php, so setting values in php.ini is not possible. Could you please tell me if this configuration can be done in any other file/location?