# Is there an image size limit, when uploading images to a server in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to upload images to my server via HTML form, using JQuery and Python. The resulting image is never bigger than 25 112 bytes. What am I doing wrong?

```py
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

try: 
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage()


def fbuffer(f, chunk_size=10000):
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk: break
        yield chunk


fileitem = form['userfile']

if fileitem.filename:

    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    f = open('files/' + fn, 'wb', 10000)

    for chunk in fbuffer(fileitem.file):
      f.write(chunk)
    f.close()
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
```

Comment: This is more likely determined by the server configuration than by the code on either side, I think. Are you in full control over both ends, and if so can you expound on that?

Comment: Yes, I am.
server.py
```python
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 7102)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```
What's there that I can configure?

Comment: `nginx` and whatever on your server is managing the firewall, most likely. This isn't my area of expertise, so someone else'll have to zero in on the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Increasing file upload limit in apache httpd file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53956590/15046005)

There is the answer to your question.

> You don't need to do anything in your httpd file.
> For increase files size you need to edit php.ini where you find this two optins : >post_max_size & upload_max_filesize